# SoftwareSerial.h alternative with AVR (Two Serial/UART ports in atmega328p)

Tags: serial, atmega328, softwareserial, uart

`Arduino` pins can be used as `UART` using the `SoftwareSerial.h` library. Is there any alternative for `AVR`?

I need more than one serial port on a `ATmega328P`, but i don't use `Arduino`.

`SoftwareSerial.h` is tied to `Arduino.h` and `Arduino` pins. I do not use `Arduino`, i use `avr-gcc` with `atmega328p` and `atmega8`.

Comment: Sorry my english

Comment: Software serial should only be used as an absolute last resort. If you are having to look at using it then you aren't using the right microcontroller.  Don't just use a certain microcontroller "because you always have", or "because the arduino uses it" - use the right one for that job, and if you need multiple serial connections then choose one that has multiple serial ports in it.  There's plenty to choose from, even within the same family of chips, that provide more than one serial port, so would require minimal changes to your project to use them.

Answer (score 2):

[AVR274](http://www.atmel.com/Images/AVR274.pdf) describes a single-wire, half-duplex software UART.

[AVR304](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc0941.pdf) describes a half-duplex, interrupt-driven software UART, and [AVR305](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc0952.pdf) describes a polled alternative.

[AVR307](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc4300.pdf) describes implementing a half-duplex UART using a USI.

All code associated with each app note can be downloaded from Atmel's website.

Comment: where can I download them?

Comment: Do a search on the app note handle.